Mount an encrypted partition from linux HD ext4 in WSL
Having dual boot, 1 SSD for Windows, 1 for linux,
It is possible to mount a linux ext4 Drive/Partition in WSL in Windows 11 with:
wsl --mount <DiskPath> --partition <PartitionNumber> --type <Filesystem>

Source
Is there any way to mount correctly a partition that is encrypted with LUKS

For dual boot (being in the linux system) recommendations:

check id of the user that owns the partition (can be done in wsl later).
check partition sizes with lsblk, because they can have entirely different names under WSL, in order to identify the encrypted one, later.

in Powershell [admin]
# identify disk
GET-CimInstance -query "SELECT * from Win32_DiskDrive"

# mount disk (DiskPath: \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE*)
wsl --mount <DiskPath> --bare

in WSL:
# 1
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cryptsetup

# 2 identify partition of interest
lsblk

# 3 Mount the encrypted partition
sudo cryptsetup open /dev/sdXn cryptpart

# 4 create mountpoint and mount
sudo mkdir /mnt/your-mount-point
sudo mount /dev/mapper/cryptpart /mnt/your-mount-point

# 5 check ownership of partition and of logged user
ls -l /mnt/your-mount-point/
id USERNAME
# if they match, proceed to read/modify files

# 7 Unmount
sudo umount /mnt/your-mount-point
sudo cryptsetup close cryptpart

if ID that owns the mounted partition is different from the logged WSL user ID
# create a user with the id of
# the owner of /mnt/your-mount-point

EXISTING_UID=<id-of-owner-of-files-in-mount-point>
NEWUSER=<your_username> # name can be different from linux system name

# use oneliner removing \
# this example requires zsh installed
useradd --create-home --shell /usr/bin/zsh --user-group --groups \ 
adm,dialout,cdrom,floppy,sudo,audio,dip,video,plugdev,netdev --uid \
$EXISTING_UID --password $(read -sp Password: pw ; echo $pw | openssl passwd \
-1 -stdin) $NEWUSER

# change default user, for vscode purposes, modify `/etc/wsl.conf`
# adding username when its id is not 1000
[user]
default=username-when-its-id-is-not-1000



